# How to isolate an I2C Bus from its controller for large RGB strip projects?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, i2c, led-strip, rgb

Last year I controlled my RGB, 5v (not 12v) strips with a Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi was powered separately from the lights via a 5v barrel supply. Everything worked mostly ok. Some erratic flashing was noticed. I may have needed a level booster on the i2c or less wire from the Pi to the strips. Decided to avoid the headache and get a strip controller instead.

This year I got this inline [controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DDB6JHJ). I tried to power it separately from the strip, but it kept on faulting once connected. I then powered it by tying it to the strip power (grabbing power from the last strip). It worked until the lights got to a certain brightness, then the controller would fault (likely could not handle the voltage drop, lights do fine though).The controller worked great besides that (no flickering).

**Can you think of any way I can plug the controller into a separate power source (IE: a 5 or 12v wall wart), but still have it speak to the RGB strips via I2C so I can run the lights at full brightness?**

My hypothesis currently is the the Raspberry Pi worked with sperate power from the lights because of some sort of isolation mechanism. Is there any way to implement that isolation mechanism for the less sophisticated controller?

Comment: Describe that first fault of powering it separately. Whatever it was, the issue was not isolation which has a specific and relatively exotic meaning. That means the Rapsberry Pi would not have isolation. And post a schematic of the setup with separate power supplies that was faulting.

Comment: I'll make the schematic in a bit, but basically the fault is that the controller went non-responsive.

Comment: Might be latch up from improper power sequencing. An application processor like an RPI usually has supervisors to handle power sequencing. A cheap LED controller probably does not and wouldn't be expecting an external voltage source other than its own.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding I don't think that controller supports i2c either.

Comment: The controller works (controls everything via I2c) but only if the LED strip is not at full intensity.